# Using Bash-variables in sqlite

Tags: sql, bash, sqlite

thanks for taking your time to take a look at this.
I recently started to script in Bash and wanted to write a small script where the user input, depending on the chosen parameter, gets written in a sqlite database. I'm completly stuck, if you have a minute and an idea I'd be very greatful if you answer to this.
My code currently looks somethink like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
### checking if database is availibe etc.
## ...

if [ $# -gt 0 ]
  case $1 in
    "--add")
         case $2 in
             "-t") 
                 sqlite3 DatabaseFile <<'END_SQL'
                    INSERT INTO databasenaem (tablename) ($3);
                 END_SQL
#           ....          

         esac
     "--change")
        sqlite3 DatabaseFile <<'END_SQL'
           UPDATE tablename SET tablename=$3 where ID=3;
        END_SQL
esac
```

Thank you very much and have a great day.

Comment: Please paste your script first at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your tip, I will do. The code here is not my complete script since it's more a bash to sql problem I only posted what I thougt would be interesting in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to provide complete answer, as the structure of the tables in the database are not listed, and there is no sample data to replicate the problem.

With the little information that is available, 2 possible problems:

- From the SQL statement, looks like the injected parameters are string. You have to quote them to create valid sql
- The code uses quotes for the 'here-document' separator. This will disable the parameter substibution that will be needed to expand $3 and friends.

Also, check the spelling (e.g., 'databasename')

Consider the following

```
sqlite3 DatabaseFile <<END_SQL
    INSERT INTO databasenaem (tablename) ('$3');
END_SQL

...

sqlite3 DatabaseFile <<END_SQL
    UPDATE tablename SET tablename='$3' where ID=3;
END_SQL
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried it with the ' ' but the only thing I got was that it then safed litterly $3 as value to the table. The spellingmistakes happend when I tried to shorten the code so there are not to many lines here. If it helps I can post the whole code

Comment: Can you provide the exact input to replicate the problem. On my machine, using the unquoted END_SQL, $3 was replaced by it's value

Comment: I'm Sorry -had a Problem in the 8th layer - forgot to unquote the END_SQL and just quoted '$3' - it works fine now. Thank you very much and have a great day :)